# Raspberry Pi Arduino I2C communication

Tags: c#, c++, arduino, i2c, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to connect a Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IoT Core to an Arduino Uno R3 via I2C in order to send some data from the Pi to the Arduino. 
Either the Arduino I2cDevice in C# is evaluated to null, or it isn't but when I send data the Arduino doesn't receive anything.

**My Arduino code**

```cpp
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  while (1 < Wire.available()) {
    char c = Wire.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
  int x = Wire.read();
  Serial.println(x);
}
```

**My Raspberry Pi code**

```cs
var i2cSettings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0X26);
i2cSettings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode;
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector());
var arduino = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id, i2cSettings);
arduino.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world"));
```

Edit: I dont know if it changes anything, but I also have a touchscreen connected to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Did you give your arduino an address at Wire.begin(); ?

Comment: Yes. I gave the address 0x26 (Wire.begin(0x26);)

Comment: Could you add some debug output to it?

Comment: I made some edits(add await) on your c# code. And test with Raspberry Pi and Arduino Uno, it works. Use updated code to test and show us hardware pins connections between the two devices.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Thank you! I will do so as soon as I get home!

Comment: @wawa What do you mean? It doesn't throw any exceptions...it just doesn't work

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT https://imgur.com/a/nph5x Here you go

Comment: @Azeros From your images, the hardware connections are right. Did you use [official Slave Receiver Code](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter)?

Comment: @Azeros Still, I can't reproduce your issue. If possible you can share your windows iot core project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether or not this is also the same which I experienced in the past. Due to the different Voltage between Arduino 5V version and Raspberry Pi, you need to use level shifter in the middle of the connection.

https://core-electronics.com.au/tutorials/how-to-use-logic-level-shifters-converters.html